# Vue.js 2 : Computed array iteration

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm having a problem updating array even though in the dev tools it updated its status. Sure its something simple! Any ideas? or if there's a smarter way to do this let me know! :) Thanks!

**Getting Data**

```
get('/skills')
    .then((res) => {
        this.skillSet = res.data
    })
```

**Computed**

```
computed: {
        skillFiltered() {
           return this.skillSet = this.skillSet.map(res => ({
                value: res.id,
                label: res.name,
                disabled: false
            }))
           .filter( res =>  res.disabled === false) 
        },
    }
```

**Methods**

```
 methods: {
  updateComputed() {
   this.skillSet[0].disabled = true;
  }
 }
```

Comment: So you are not able to filter disabled skills from the array?

Comment: What updateComputed should do ?

Comment: As far as I can see all of them are disabled by default, so there's no real reason to use the second filter.

Comment: @MichałKostrzyński The filter becomes usefull after some updates with updateComputed.

Comment: Faly, how? It's always returned with `disabled: false` before the filter has a chance to kick in.

Comment: @MichałKostrzyński I see, you're right

Comment: @Faly whenever i  use the updateComputed(). I'm expecting `this.skillSet[0]` will be remove since the item `skillsSet[0] ` is true

Answer (score 0):

You need a different structure for settable computed's.

Ref [Computed-Setter](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter)